# how to trace an application's behavior?

Tags: android, security, trace, strace

I want to build an app that would be able to trace what other apps, processes and services doing. The purpose is to analyze their behavior so I can protect some critical assets on the SmartPhone like Photo Album, Contacts, Camera Operation...

I am working on a rooted Android smartphone 4.1.2.

- What is the best way to trace an app's behavior?

I have already cross-compiled **strace** command on Android to trace System Calls but it seems that i can't trace sophisticated operations apart from files manipulation.

- Is there a way to trace Object creations? For example, if an app want to uses the Camera it has to create a Camera Object.
- What is the suitable Android architecture lever I should searching for traces? (Kernel, Application Framework, Libraries,...)

This is my first question on stack, so please forgive me for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point for you would be to scrap the logcat, from a "normal" app you don't have access to the process of other apps, it's android's security model you'll get struck by.

Comment: Scraping the LogCat won't reveal anything about an app's behavior. The idea is to search or traces on system which are triggered from the application layer and analyze them. I think that Logcat can't produce such info

Comment: In other words, you'd like to programatically use ddms, right? Basically ddms does what you'd like to accomplish, if I've understood correct.

Comment: have you taken a look at this api?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html

Comment: Using ddms can with execution traces about my application. I don't think I can use it for tracing other apps. Can I? The Debug API I think is used to trace your application's execution behavior. Please correct me if i'm wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Each app have its own permissions, so you will not expect an app to use camera if it doesn't have a permission to use the camera.

You can always see how many apps are active right now. What apps are using internet? You can put sniffer and see what they are sending, may be they send some sensitive user data?

You can scan the log cat for different system operations that got triggered once an app is fired.

And finally you can check the memory usage of the device to see suspicious behaviors there.

There are probably more more things you can do, but this is what came to my mind right now.

Comment: The permissions perspective is right. The sniffer idea is useful. But I am trying this different approach which indicates an “on the fly” tracing technique. Are there Logcat traces when an app uses the cam or accessing the contact list? As far as I know there aren't any.

Comment: @Babibu I think that the memory usage can be a great answer to his prayers, but is there any way to dump the memory, or monitor it at runtime?